# Angular JS - Generate Check box and text box based on JSON

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I need to create new HTML elements(In my case checkbox) based on JSON. Tried and got the checkbox for each book listed based on the type of contents array in books. But I need to loop further to find on Selection array for each book at the time checkbox is clicked and create the textbox for sold copies and for remaining copies for that specific book. Some help will be appreciated to find on Selection array and create text boxes(each one for sold copies and remaining copies) when specific checkbox(book) is clicked. Thanks in advance

mybooks.json

```
"mycollection" : {
    "title" : "Books",
    "contents" : [
        {
            "title" : "Book1",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Book2",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Book3",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX",
            "onSelection" : [
                {
                    "title" : "Sold Copies",
                    "type" : "TEXT"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "Remaining Copies",
                    "type" : "TEXT"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title" : "Book4",
            "type" : "CHECKBOX",
            "onSelection" : [
                {
                    "title" : "",
                    "type" : "TEXT"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

templates.json

```
{
"textboxTemplate": "<input type='text' name='firstname'>",
"checkboxTemplate": "<div style='margin-top:70px,margin-left:50px'><label class='containerr'><input type='checkbox' id = 'myCheck' checked='checked'><span class='checkmarkk'></span></label><div id='personalhis_title' style='margin-left:30px'>{{content.title}}</div></div>"
}
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApppli', []);
app.config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
   $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', '**']);
});

app.constant('URL', 'json/');

app.factory('BookService', function ($http, URL) {
   var getBooks = function () {
      return $http.get(URL + 'mybooks.json');
   };
   return {
      getBooks: getBooks
   };
});

app.factory('TemplateService', function ($http, URL) {
   var getTemplates = function () {
      return $http.get(URL + 'templates.json');
   };
   return {
      getTemplates: getTemplates
   };
});
app.controller('contl', function (BookService) {
   var ctrll = this;
   ctrll.content = [];
   ctrll.fetchContent = function () {
      BookService.getBooks().then(function (result) {
         ctrll.content = result.data.mycollection.contents;
      });
   };
   ctrll.fetchContent();
});

app.directive('contentItem', function ($compile, TemplateService) {
   var getTemplate = function (templates, type) {
      var types = type.type;
      var template = '';                    
      switch (types) {
         case 'textbox':
            template = templates.textboxTemplate;
            break;
         case 'CHECKBOX':
            template = templates.checkboxTemplate;
            break;
      }
      return template;
  };
  var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
     TemplateService.getTemplates().then(function (response) {
        var templates = response.data;
        element.html(getTemplate(templates, scope.content));
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
     });
  };
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     link: linker,
     scope: {
        content: '='
     }
  };
});
```

index.html

```
<div id="containerr" ng-controller="contl as ctrll">
    <content-item ng-repeat="item in ctrll.content" content="item">
    </content-item>
</div>
```

Comment: do i understand correctly - you want to add checkbox next to each book, and after select some of them - click ex. button which push all selected books?

Comment: I need to list all books with title next to checkbox for each book. Completed that. On selecting or clicking a checkbox i need to add two text boxes adjacent to book title to input number of sold copies and number of remaining copies for that particular book